# Is there a list of plural names of currencies?

Tags: grammatical-number, money

Is anyone aware of a list of plural names of currencies?  I don't really care what conventions are used. I just want to avoid using an obviously wrong plural form.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Which country/currency? Do you have examples?

Comment: This is for a computer program.  There are currently about 30 currencies, but that could change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wiktionary has a category for everything, including one for [currencies](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category%3aen%3aCurrency), with currently 289 entries.

Comment: You said little about **plural** form of the names specifically. So it is with the Wikt page by itself. Eventually, the process would be the same as with the TFD method I suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Invariant plurals:

- Yen (Japan)
- Sen (fraction of a yen, Japan)
- Yuan (China)
- Jiao (fraction of a yuan, China)
- Fen (fraction of a jiao, China)
- Baht (Thailand)
- Satang (fraction of a baht, Thailand)
- Rand (South Africa)
- Quid (British slang)

Irregular plurals:

- Penny / pence (fraction of a pound, United Kindom only)
- Paisa / paise (fraction of a rupee in India and Pakistan)
- Drachma / drachmae or drachmas (Greece, formerly)
- Krona / kronor (Sweden)
- Krone / kroner (Norway and Denmark)
- Markka / Markkaa (Finland, formerly)
- Lira / lire (Italy, formerly)
- Real / reais (Brazil)

Regular plurals:

- Dollar / dollars
- Euro / euros
- Cent / cents (fraction of a dollar or euro)
- Penny / pennies (Canada and United States)
- Pound / pounds
- Franc / Francs (France formerly and still in parts of Africa)
- Centime / Centimes (fraction of a franc)
- Rupee / rupees (India and Pakistan)
- Dinar / dinars (with dihram, several states in the Middle East and North Africa)
- Dihram / dihrams
- Ruble / rubles (Russia and other former SSRs)
- Peso / pesos (Mexico and several Latin American countries)
- Bitcoin / bitcoins (no comment)
- Loonie / loonies (Canadian slang)

Of course there are many, many other named coins and currencies. Some of which, yes, may be irregular. However, the anglicized standard pluralization (stick an 's' on it, basically) is accepted in most cases.

Comment: At the end of the day, nobody's going to call you out for saying "Satangs" instead of Satang.

Comment: Under invariant plurals, you can add *sen* which is 1/100th of a yen.

Comment: I wonder if it would be better to eliminate named coins from the list? Ie. pennies of a dollar, and loonies. They aren't names of currency, strictly speaking.

Comment: The internationally recognized nomenclature and technical descriptions of currencies, are codified in the International Organization for Standardization (ISO) standard ISO_4217. Ref https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217.

Comment: @AdamBrown fun fact, I am here now because someone decided to keep on saying Korean Won as wons In a video, and I cannot pay attention to what is being said

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach could be to check the dictionary as and when the need arises for an individual currency-name; e.g.,

> **lev**  (lf) *n. pl.* **lev·a** (lv) ([TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lev))

Take off from the TFD [*Currency Table: Listed by Country*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/currency), look up the currency against the country, say if the currency is *lev*, click on it to go to the respective definition page. Alternately, use the *Currency Table: Listed by Basic Unit (Bold) and Subunit*, on the same page.

The default plural, of course, is the usual +*s*, so if the definition page does not expressly show a plural, you know.